# Texstudio: Page Number in the PDF Previw Panel

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

In Texmate, there is an amazing feature in that it shows the page number on the left of the preview PDF page. You can then simply jump to that page by clicking the number (see figure below).

Is there something similar in Texstudio?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can directly edit the page number in the toolbar:
   [image: Edit page number]
2. There's also a page overview, which can be activated via the context menu of the embedded viewer (if the viewer is windowed also via the menu of the viewer window):
   [image: Page overview]